# Databinding techniques

Tags: wpf, data-binding

How do I bind a textbox to one to many valued columns.

my table: id name statusid typeid assignerid ...

I would like to bind all these to textboxes. Some of the options are:

i.make joins and form resultset accordingly<1, tom, new, query, george>
ii.bind the sub table values to combobox and set selected value property accordingly

are there any other techniques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution  using Entity framework. EF is too cool!

Comment: Even though Josh's solution was apt as a WPF beginner I realised EF can do better as I progressed!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4, look into the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) control. It's a tabular list control that supports editing similar to a spreadsheet UI.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status"
                                ItemsSource="{StaticResource Statuses}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding StatusID}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```